Multimap will not accept player inputted name
I'm currently trying to implement a leader board using multi-map which lets the player input their name.
it works when I give it a normal string but for some reason wont accept the player inputted string, I know the player inputted string is correct as I'm printing it in console and it is correct but the printScore function isn't printing it
LeaderBoard.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class LeaderBoard
{
private:

    std::multimap<std::string, int> scores; 

public:
    LeaderBoard() : scores()
    {
    }

    void newScore(std::string playerName, int playerScore);

    void printScores();
};

LeaderBoard.cpp
#include "LeaderBoard.h"
#include <iostream>
void LeaderBoard::newScore(std::string playerName, int playerScore)
{
    std::cout << "score added" << std::endl;
    scores.insert(std::make_pair(playerName, playerScore));
}

void LeaderBoard::printScores()
{
    std::cout << "Player Scores:" << std::endl;
    for (auto it = scores.rbegin(); it != scores.rend(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second <<std::endl;
    }
}

Main.cpp
LeaderBoard leaderBoard;
bool newScoreAdded = false;
bool nameFinished = false;
std::string playerName;
std::string EnteredPlayerName;
std::string testname = "tester";

leaderBoard.newScore(testname, 10);

while (window.isOpen())
{
   while (window.pollEvent(event))
   {
       if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
        window.close();
       }
       else if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered && player.playerDead == true) {
           if (event.text.unicode < 128) {
               if (event.text.unicode == '\b' && EnteredPlayerName.size() > 0) {
                EnteredPlayerName.pop_back();
               }
               else if (event.text.unicode != '\b' && event.text.unicode != '\n') {
                EnteredPlayerName += static_cast<char>(event.text.unicode);
            }
        }
    }
    
}

if (nameFinished == true && newScoreAdded == false)
{

    playerName = EnteredPlayerName;
    cout << "player name: " << playerName << endl;
    leaderBoard.newScore(playerName, EnemiesKilled);
    leaderBoard.printScores();
    newScoreAdded = true;
}

if (player.playerDead == true && nameFinished == false)
{
    window.draw(EnterNameHere);
    playerNameText.setString(EnteredPlayerName);
    playerNameText.setPosition(EnterNameHere.getPosition().x + 80, EnterNameHere.getPosition().y + 25);
    window.draw(playerNameText);

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Enter))
    {
        nameFinished = true;
    }

  }
}


all the couts will print and the tester score prints, but only the score will print for the player input, not the name

examples need to be MINIMAL.   That means removing all code that you can where the problem doesn't go away.   Also, it needs to be compilable trivially so you need to put all the relevant code into one listing, not split across files.  As it stands now it's likely to be closed.

This issue was that i was using the enter key, pressing enter makes a new line making it so it didn't recognise the string, instead I opted for making a button for submitting the player name
